# connecting web client to server with IP and port with different URI prefix

Tags: jquery, html, sockets, websocket, client-server

I want to write a client in html, and I should connect to a server implemented in c++ language and I know the IP address and port number it is assigned to.

But I don't know what library and tool to use. 
I searched and found WebSocket and etc but as I understood we can use them if we have server and client that both of them have used Websocket.
But here just my client should use socket in html and connect to IP address of server through the port specified.
Can I use JQuery or something like that in my html file for socket programming?
I searched but all the methods use servers URL or by localhost.
But here I have IP and port.
conclusion : I need to connect to a socket in a syntax like this in C:

```
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
```

edit:
Well, I asked someone and he told me to use a proxy server. By using the [flash network library](http://theintencity.com/flash-network/#realtimesocket) for connecting my writen server in C and proxy and using [socket.io](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) with Node.js to connect proxy and html client.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advace;
Nahid.